# Cassandra Range Query : Secondary Index vs Unindexed Colum

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have seen that the best way to do range query on cassandra is by using CLUSTERING KEY. But I need to do some range query other than CLUSTERING KEY columns.

I read that we can do it on any column using ALLOW FILTERING. But is there any performance advantage if I create secondary index on that column ?

Comment: Performance is going to suck with **both** ALLOW FILTERING *and* a secondary index.  If performance is something you really care about, you'll need to duplicate your data into a query table, with a primary key definition designed to support your range query.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link:
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2

The `ALLOW FILTERING` option allows you tell Cassandra that it is ok to perform in-memory filtering of the data once it loads rows from disk. So we can use this to search by a clustering column without specifying the previous clustering columns. But we can't use it on non-clustering columns.

See the below example schema from the blog. Use of `ALLOW FILTERING` doesn't allow us to filter by author column until we make it an index, which then doesn't need the `ALLOW FILTERING` option.

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE author = 'john' ALLOW FILTERING;
Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator
cqlsh:test>

cqlsh:test> CREATE INDEX authors ON blogs (author);

cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE author = 'john';
(0 rows)
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE author = 'john' ALLOW FILTERING;
(0 rows)
```

Comment: But RANGE QUERY still need ALLOW FILTERING even if it is indexed. Right ?

Comment: I just made an experiment. Cassandra allows RANGE query on unindexed columns. Only range query.